# Shopping Cart - update total amount after sales tax change - without reloading page using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, shopping-cart, authorize.net

From what I understand, in order to update a page or calculate a price without it reloading, I have to use ajax.  Correct?

I have a shopping cart, that gives subtotal, tax, and grand total.  User has to select their state in order to know whether we charge for tax or not.  Then, they click "checkout", which is actually a button tied to Authorize.net. My client doesn't want pages to reload or refresh so I have to use Ajax to update the page once they choose their state.

Authorize.net has a set of variables such as `$amount_var`, `$loginID`, `$transactionKey`, etc. They use those variables and place them into their "hidden" values to be sent off for processing. I am attempting to change the `$amount_var` variable to equal my total calculated amount, which was processed in the php page accessed by ajax.

The state dropdown menu has `onchange="doStateTax()"`.  Where `GRANDtotalprice` is a hidden field with a running total of all the items in the cart, and `ddl` is whichever state they chose.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doStateTax(){
        var grandtotalX = $('#GRANDtotalprice').val();
        var statetaxX = $('#ddl').val();

        $.post('statetax_query.php',
        {statetaxX:statetaxX, grandtotalX:grandtotalX}, 
        function(data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('.products-placeholder').html(data.products);     
            $('.statetax-placeholder').html(data.statetax);     
            $('.total-placeholder').html(data.total);
            // ...
        });
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

This posts to a PHP page where it checks to see if the state = "michigan".  If so, they get charged 6% tax.  Here is my PHP page that does the calculations:

```
 <?php
    if (($_POST['statetaxX'] == 'MI'))
    {
        $taxselect = .06;
        $taxselect1 = 1.06;
    }
    else
    {
        $taxselect = 0;
        $taxselect1 = 1;
    }

    $products = number_format(($_POST['grandtotalX']), 2, '.', '');
    $tax = number_format((($_POST['grandtotalX'])*($taxselect)), 2, '.', '');
    $total = number_format((($_POST['grandtotalX'])*($taxselect1)), 2, '.', '');

    $results = array(
       'products' => $products,
       'statetax' => $tax,
       'total' => $total
    );
    $json = json_encode($results);
    echo $json;
?>
```

Here's where I lose thought on how the process works... I thought that the results go back in what is called a "success callback" right?  I do see the subtotal, tax, and total changing instantly so that DOES work.  It displays the numbers in a   because of this code here:

```
$('.total-placeholder').html(data.total);
```

But this only DISPLAYS the results.  How or where in my code do I cause Authorize.net to change their `$amount_var` variable into my total?  Again, their part of code has this located on my php shopping cart near the bottom of the page:

```
$amount_var = "youramount;
$loginID        = "loginid";
$transactionKey = "transkey";
```

It would be super easy if I could just inject my success callback into their hidden field called `x_amount` but it isn't that easy.  They use the `$amount_var` for other reasons such as setting a fingerprint so I must set their `$amount_var` to equal my own calculations. Do I set this in the php page? Or the javascript? Elsewhere?

**EDIT:  Response Code 99 error**

Almost have it working.  After adding your code, I get a response code 99 error.  When I select a state that does NOT require tax, it works.  When I select MI (michigan) it gives Response Code 99.  From what I've found this is because there is a mismatch between this part:

```
<input type='hidden' name='x_amount' value='<?php echo $amount; ?>' />
```

and this:

```
// The following lines generate the SIM fingerprint.  PHP versions 5.1.2 and
// newer have the necessary hmac function built in.  For older versions, it
// will try to use the mhash library.
if( phpversion() >= '5.1.2' )
    { $fingerprint = hash_hmac("md5", $loginID . "^" . $sequence . "^" . $timeStamp .     "^" . $amount . "^", $transactionKey); }
else 
    { $fingerprint = bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_MD5, $loginID . "^" . $sequence . "^" .         $timeStamp . "^" . $amount . "^", $transactionKey)); }
?>
```

because of the "$amount" part in the hidden field is replaced by your script yet the "$amount part of the $fingerprint above isn't altered by the script.  I think Authorize.net requires the fingerprint part AND the hidden field to match.  Which brings me back to how to set this $amount variable to be our new combined total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## REMOVED A BUNCH OF STUFF B/C IT WAS FOR AIM METHOD

check the history of my answer if you want it

## EDIT

Have a field named `x_tax`

AFTER THIS LINE

```
$('.statetax-placeholder').html(data.statetax);
```

ADD THIS

```
$('input[name=x_tax]').val("Tax1<|>state tax<|>"+data.statetax);
```

from the bottom of page 28 of the SIM Guide: http://www.authorize.net/support/SIM_guide.pdf

> ADDITIONAL SHIPPING INFORMATION (Level 2 Data)
>   Tax
>   (x_tax)
>   Value: The valid tax amount OR delimited tax information
>   Format: When submitting delimited tax information, values must be 
>   delimited by a bracketed pipe <|>
>   Notes: The tax amount charged OR when submitting this information by 
>   means of the HTML Form POST, delimited tax information including the 
>   sales tax name, description, and amount is also allowed. 
>    tax item name<|>
>    tax description<|>
>    tax amount
>   Format: The dollar sign ($) is not allowed when submitting delimited 
>   information.
>   Note: The total amount of the transaction in x_amount must include 
>   this amount. 
>   Example:
>   state tax<|>0.0625">

## ANOTHER EDIT

On the php side generate the fingerprint in the ajax call (PHP side):

```
if( phpversion() >= '5.1.2' )
{
    $fingerprint = hash_hmac("md5", $loginID . "^" . $sequence . "^" . $timeStamp .     "^" . $amount . "^", $transactionKey);
}
else 
{
    $fingerprint = bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_MD5, $loginID . "^" . $sequence . "^" .         $timeStamp . "^" . $amount . "^", $transactionKey));
}

$results = array(
   'products' => $products,
   'statetax' => $tax,
   'total' => $total,
   'fingerprint' => $fingerprint // Pass the fingerprint
);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

On successful Ajax:

```
// Tax amount
$('input[name=x_tax]').val("Tax1<|>state tax<|>"+data.statetax);
// Total amount
$('input[name=x_amount]').val(data.total);
// use the new Fingerprint
$('input[name=x_fp_hash]').val(data.fingerprint);
```

Comment: I am using DB based cart & Authorize.net SIM.  So when the ajax posts to the php page, is THAT when I insert the calculated tax into the DB?  And does this instantly update my cart to show the tax that is calculated?  If the user selects MI (michigan) that triggers the function, sends the post, calculates the tax.  So somewhere in the php page I can just update the DB cart to show the new amount?  I didn't know this would show instantly without refreshing the page.  That's awesome if so!

Comment: 1. the user selects MI (michigan) that triggers the function, sends the post, calculates the tax, SAVES THE TAX IN THE DB CART, RETURNS THE TAX AND OTHER AMOUNTS WITH JSON. 2. Javascript gets the amounts from step 1, parses and displays them. 3. submit button is hit and another Ajax method is called, a curl request to Authorize.net is  made, with the values stored in the session (i provided some classes for achieving this above)

Comment: Wait i just read that you are using SIM method read the EDIT at the very bottom of my post

Comment: I feel like this is so close.  When clicking "submit" it not adding tax in.  I even tried manually typing this     <input name="x_tax" type="hidden" id="x_tax" value="Tax1|Sales Tax|0.06" /> and still not adding it in.  Is this something that has to be setup in Authorize.net to accept that x_tax field and add it?

Comment: I pasted a link to the sim docs, make sure you are doing everything the way it says to (I always do aim so I dont have too much experience with this) also use `<|>` as the separator not just `|`, according to the docs

Comment: I manually pasted <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" name="x_tax" VALUE="Tax1<|>state
tax<|>0.0625"> from the docs and it isn't adding it in.  Their instructions state is MUST be included in the x_amount part so my question is, why even bother with x_tax if I still have to find a way to make it show up in x_amount?  Are there instructions or etiquette rules somewhere in StackOverflow where I'm not supposed to offer to pay someone for help?  I'm in desperate need to meet a deadline by Tuesday and fear losing my job over this.

Comment: when you change x_tax,  you also need to change `x_amount` to reflect the new grand total value. `$('input[name=x_amount]').val(data.total);` This is a free help site, if you want to get a freelancer you can get one on a bunch of other sites. I could probably help you if you absolutely need someone on the quick. http://yaconiello.com use the form to start an email thread with me. (although I would try to use the free help myself)

Comment: Almost there.  Please see my EDIT above in original post.

Comment: Oh my, it WORKED!  You're a genius.  What it took was me taking all of Authorize.net variables that generate the $fingerprint (including transaction key, loginid, etc) and pasting all of those into the php page that ajax POSTS to.  I thought all that had to stay on the shopping cart page which had the checkout button.  I just placed all the code including Authorize.nets into the PHP side and I was able to add tax to the amount. I am finally understanding how AJAX works.  You're an amazing help and great at describing the solution!

Comment: Admin or Francis, when question is solved, do I completely overwrite my original code with code that is working or is this post sufficient to help future people?  Thanks

Comment: this post should be fine. although, if you want - at the bottom of your post edit it and ADD additional data, don't take away anything it could be useful to someone down the line.